# After Changing Xcode App is gives the error like some file is missing or not found

Tags: xcode

I have tried to change my app name from E2demo2 to other name . but after that it shows error that E2DEMO2-SWIFT FILE  not found. why?

Comment: How exactly did you change the name? The built-in renaming function (renaming the project file in the sidebar) is supposed to change all relevant places (except a very few in Build Settings)

Comment: i want to change all the old names

Comment: I asked you a question.

Comment: Actually I  HAVE CHANGED THE PROJECT NAME . THEN FEW OPTIONS CAME TO CHANGE IT . I HAD CHECKED ALL THE OPTIONS THEN ONLY ITS GIVES ME THE ERROR. OTHER WISE IF I UNCHECK UPPER ONE TARGET OPTION. THEN ITS WORKING FINE BUT WHILE INSTALLING THE APP IT COMES WITH OLD NAME. ONLY THE PROJECT NAME HAS CHANGED

Comment: Rename the project using all options, then go to Build Settings and look for occurrences of the old name for example in the Swift bridging header. Rename the items accordingly.